# dynamically convert timestamp into naive datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Is this a valid solution to convert a string time into a naive datetime object in a dynamic manner?
By dynamic i mean no matter where the server running this code is located i will always end up with a naive datetime object. I am afraid of missing something here

```
from time import timezone as diff_to_utc
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


time_str = "2018-09-15T15:30:00"  # here for example CEST
time_dt_utc = datetime.strptime(time_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") + \
              timedelta(seconds=diff_to_utc)
time_dt_utc
>> datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 15, 14, 30)
```

***Update to clarify my question***

I have a naive timestamp (time data without timezone information) coming from scraping a website which I assume will always be in the server's timezone (but not contain that information), and I want to convert that naive timestamp from my system's timezone into a UTC timestamp, automatically detecting what my system's timezone is in the process.

Comment: CEST is fixed here…?

Comment: And this doesn't really make sense… A naïve timestamp is one without any timezone information. I.e. 15:30:00 is just 15:30:00 without context and could refer to any number of different actual times. But obviously, you *want* to involve some timezone math here.

Comment: well in order to provide an example i used CEST, but in general it can be every timezone possible.

Comment: Wherever the code will run, the `strptime` function will assume the timezone of the machine that it is run on and create a datetime object using that timezone, then will convert to UTC using `timedelta`.

Comment: I'll take a stab at reformulating your question: you have a *naïve timestamp* (time data without timezone information) coming from your system which will always be in the system's timezone (but not contain that information), and you want to convert that naïve timestamp from your system's timezone into a UTC timestamp, automatically detecting what your system's timezone is in the process?

Comment: *"from scraping a website which I assume will always be in the server's timezone"* – What's that assumption based on? Is that reliable?

Comment: this assumption is purely made for this question. If this assumption is reliable is not relevant for the question as far as i can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in a nutshell, you want to parse a string without timezone information, but whose timezone you will *assume*, and convert it to UTC, and perhaps to a naïve timestamp in UTC. I don't know how reliable your assumption about the timezone being the system time is, but that's for you to figure out.

Let's start with this note:

> For the above Timezone constants ([...] `timezone` [...]), the value is determined by the timezone rules in effect at module load time or the last time `tzset()` is called and may be incorrect for times in the past. **It is recommended to use the `tm_gmtoff` and `tm_zone` results from `localtime()` to obtain timezone information.**

So, let's start by replacing `from time import timezone as diff_to_utc` with this:

```
import time

local_offset = time.localtime().tm_gmtoff
```

Then you simply parse your string to a naïve datetime object:

```
from datetime import datetime

time_str = '2018-09-15T15:30:00'
naive = datetime.strptime(time_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
# datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 15, 15, 30)
```

Then make that timestamp aware by adding the timezone information you have determined (in whatever way) to it:

```
from datetime import timezone, timedelta

aware = naive.astimezone(timezone(timedelta(seconds=local_offset)))
# datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 15, 15, 30, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 7200)))
```

Then, if needed, convert it to UTC:

```
utc = aware.astimezone(timezone.utc)
# datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 15, 13, 30, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

And if you somehow need it, make it naïve again:

```
naive_utc = utc.replace(tzinfo=None)
# datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 15, 13, 30)
```

Comment: Thanks for this!!! You explained it so clear and simple....